# Add force and rotate object at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: object layout and force way]

like in the picture I want to add a force to a parent object in such a way that it will rotate 90 degrees while moving right and up. I stored the position below the object to help the rotating motion but I dont know any way to put into code.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [`AddForceAtPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html)

> Applies force at position. As a result this will apply a torque and force on the object.

```
GetComponent<RigidBody>().AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.right, child.transform.position);
```

Comment: I already tried doing it but, it didn't work out. and i dont know how to search for it. the motion i want to have is just rotating the object by 90 degrees and move it right and up `code` rb2d.AddForceAtPosition(Vector3.right * speed, ex.position); `code` the code i tried

Comment: This sounds like you actually would like to hardcode it and not use the RigidBody at all ...

Comment: the motion is actually quite simple but i dont know any way to ask or search for it.  regardless, thank you